# Gson parsing varied data into an object

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I have a varied data type that is served as json which I am fetching through retrofit. Here is how it looks, when the message type is an image

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("54cd78c79ce8756749a8e38c"),
    "data": {
        "image_name": "10347646_865379743494769_4408387832275449094_n.png",
        "image_url": "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/clan/e492006e561fe3811e3e16c85d384cf6.png",
        "image_size": 76586
    },
    "receiver_id": "54cd2fb7847828d73ce9047d",
    "sender_id": ObjectId("54cd4354bb8c1b2540bad504"),
    "server_recieved_at": ISODate("2015-02-01T00:52:23.676Z"),
    "sent_at": ISODate("2015-02-01T00:52:23.676Z"),
    "created_at": ISODate("2015-02-01T00:52:23.676Z"),
    "needs_push": true,
    "type": "image",
    "status": "sent",
    "__v": 0
}
```

The message type can vary, which can either be a video, an image or text. For video, the data looks like this:

```
"data": {
        "video_name": "aa_n.mp4",
        "video_url": "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/clan/aa_n.png",
        "video_size": 76586
    },
```

A message type is specified in the json, which tells what type of data is present.

How can I deserialise this data in GSON. I created a generic MessageData class and class for both video and image. But I am not able to understand set the data with gson.

Updating the question. Here is my message class.

```
@Parcel
public class Message {

    @SerializedName("sender_id")
    private String senderId;

    @SerializedName("receiver_id")
    private String receiverId;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;

    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;

    @SerializedName("read_status")
    private boolean readStatus;

    @SerializedName("text")
    private String text;

    @SerializedName("needs_push")
    private boolean needsPush;

    //TODO Need to set the data variable


    public String getSenderId() {
        return senderId;
    }

    public void setSenderId(String senderId) {
        this.senderId = senderId;
    }

    public String getReceiverId() {
        return receiverId;
    }

    public void setReceiverId(String receiverId) {
        this.receiverId = receiverId;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public boolean isReadStatus() {
        return readStatus;
    }

    public void setReadStatus(boolean readStatus) {
        this.readStatus = readStatus;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public boolean isNeedsPush() {
        return needsPush;
    }

    public void setNeedsPush(boolean needsPush) {
        this.needsPush = needsPush;
    }
```

I have created image and video classes.

```
@Parcel
public class Image {

    @SerializedName("image_size")
    private Double imageSize;

    @SerializedName("image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    @SerializedName("image_name")
    private String imageName;
}
```

According to the json object, the message data object would be something different, which can either be an image or video. How can I serialise that into a gson object based on the type.

Answer (score 2):

For example you have JSONArray to parse with GSON, so do this:

```
     for(int i=1;i < array.length();i++) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            MessageData contact = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(array.getJSONObject(i)), MessageData.class);

//UPDATE:         
       for(int i=0;i<=contact.getData().size()-1;i++){  
        System.out.println(contact.getData().get(i));  
       }  
        //Here take the data with contact.getTitle() ecc...
        }
```

And the MessageData.class (change attribute with yours):

```
 public class MessageData {
//UPDATE
        @SerializedName("data")
        private List<string> data;  

        @SerializedName("url")
        private String url;

        @SerializedName("title")

        private String title;

        @SerializedName("score")
        private String score;

        @SerializedName("source")
        private String source;



 public List<string> getData() {  
  return data;  
 }  
 public void setData(List<string> data) {  
  this.data = data;  
 }  
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public String getScore() {
            return score;
        }

        public void setScore(String score) {
            this.score = score;
        }

        public String getSource() {
            return source;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I cannot infer how I can set different objects based on that particular type. I have updated the question to clarify my class definitions.

Comment: What I am inferring is that if the data is not a List<String> object but rather a custom object that is not predefined, but would change how would I account for that.

Comment: you can set List<Object> no?

Comment: But the difficult part is, I dont know what the Object would be. It can either be an Image or Video depending on the type. I was thinking about creating a generic class and setting it that, but I am not very sure about it.

Comment: @itsyogesh if you try my method work, after you get contact.getData().get(i) you check if is video or image..for example switch(contact.getData().get(i)){ case("video_name"): do something case ("image_name"): do something}